# Can't connect to local mail server (MDAEMON) from outside

Tags: email, firewall

I have a mail server in our local network that run through Kerio firewall. I open tcp 110 port, and try to get mail from Mdaemon to Gmail, but all in vain.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure that this question's been abandoned... But, I'm waiting for a server to reboot and there's nothing better to do atm....  MDaemon's a good product that we've used for quite some time (with some headbanging, unfortunately).

TCP Port 110 is used by the POP protocol, normally (but not always) used by mail clients to read email from a mail server.

There's nothing special about how MDaemon uses POP, other than that it can be turned of for the entire server or for individual accounts.

POP isn't what's used to get mail from your MDaemon server to Gmail, though (unless you're telling your gmail account to ALSO check mail on an outside mail server).  In most situations, you'll use SMTP over port 25 to exchange mail between servers.  (MDaemon supports a feature called "DomainPOP" where you can use Port 110 to collect mail from another server for local distribution based on other headers, but it's not used very often.)

The question sounds like you're trying to SEND email from your local server to an account on Gmail.  You'll need to have TCP port 25 open outbound through your firewall to send mail.  That doesn't mean that the remote host has to accept mail from you -- but it will make the initial handshake possible.

Usually, a fully configured mail server will have a public IP address and DNS name that directs SMTP traffic to it.  It's strongly reccommended that your domain DNS have an MX record that points to your mail server.  Ideally, there should be a reverse DNS pointer for the mail server.

Because of all the SPAM in the world, many mail servers refuse connections from other hosts that don't have a DNS record and a reverse pointer.  That's not the only reason they refuse connections, of course, but it's one.

Anyways, I expect the original user had one of three possibilities: 1) They needed SMTP open in their firewall when they opened POP instead;
2) They had POP turned off for their MDaemon account (can gmail even be configured to act as a pop client for another account?); or 3) they got blocked because of a bad dns record/pointer combination.